# How to get optional result in insert statements with Doobie?

Tags: scala, doobie

I have an optional insert query:

```
val q = sql"insert into some_table (some_field) select 42 where ...(some condition)"
```

Running this query with:

```
q.update.withUniqueGeneratedKeys[Option[Long]]("id")
```

fails with

> Result set exhausted: more rows expected

then `condition` is false.

How to get `Optional[Long]` result from insert statements with Doobie?

---

**UPD**

`.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")` gives just `Long` in for comprehension

```
val q = sql"insert into some_table (some_field) select 42 where ...(some condition)"
for {
  id <- q.update.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")   // id is long
  _ <- if (<id is present>) <some other inserts> else <nothing>
} yield id
```

How to check `id`?

Comment: The documentation says `withUniqueGeneratedKeys` expects exactly one row. Maybe `withGeneratedKeys` (which returns a Stream of all of them) works better here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thilo commented, you can use the use `withGeneratedKeys` which gives you back a `Stream[F, Long]` (where `F` is your effect type)

```scala
val result = q.update.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")
```

Here is the [doc](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/07-Updating.html#retrieving-results).

Comment: `.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")` gives just `Long` in for comprehension. See UPD. How to handle this problem?

Comment: This is a `for-comprehension` on a `Stream`, so indeed it's a `Long`, if the `Stream` happens to be empty  nothing get done, so you are safe to remove the `if` statement