# Doobie. Compose .update.withGeneratedKeys() and .update.run

Tags: scala, batch-insert, doobie

Referencing to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342218/how-to-get-optional-result-in-insert-statements-with-doobie) question.
I want to insert some entity by some condition. It can either be inserted or not. If the condition is true the entity is inserted. I want to insert some other data in various tables. It looks like this:

```
val q = sql"insert into some_table (some_field) select 42 where ...(some condition)"

val inserts = List(
  sql"insert ...",
  sql"insert ...",
  sql"insert ..."
)

for {
  id <- q.update.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")   
  _ <- inserts.reduce(_ ++ _).update.run
} yield id
```

The problem is this does not compile because the first insert is a `fs2.Stream` but the second one is not.

I was trying to replace `_ <- inserts.reduce...` with `_ = inserts.reduce`. The app can compile but `inserts` in the second line does not occur.

---

**UPD**
My possible way to solve this problem:

```
...
for {
  idOpt <- q.update.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id").compile.last   
  _ <- idOpt.fold(0.pure[ConnectionIO])(_ => inserts.reduce(_ ++ _).update.run)
} yield idOpt
```

This works, but IMHO this is not pretty. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you could ask to doobie gitter https://gitter.im/tpolecat/doobie

Comment: @gekomad unfortunatelly, gitter banned on my current workplace. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to perform your batch inserts - if you have similar data - is to use `updateMany` - [see doc](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/07-Updating.html#batch-updates):

```scala
import doobie._
type PersonInfo = (String, Option[Short])

def insertMany(ps: List[PersonInfo]): ConnectionIO[Int] = {
  val sql = "insert into person (name, age) values (?, ?)"
  Update[PersonInfo](sql).updateMany(ps)
}

// Some rows to insert
val data = List[PersonInfo](
  ("Frank", Some(12)),
  ("Daddy", None))
```

Also, if you remove`.compile.last`, you can use the fact that if your resulting `Stream` `q.update.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")` is `empty`, you 'exit early' the `for-comprehension`.

So all in all, here is what you could do:

```scala
import fs2.Stream

val result =
  // Now the for-comprehension operates on a Stream instead of an Option
  for {
    r <- q.update.withGeneratedKeys[Long]("id")   
    _ <- Stream.eval(insertMany(data)) // insertMany(data) is defined like in the snippet above
  } yield r

result.compile.last
```